# google analytics api in php website

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics

I am creating a custom reporting website, where I want to show live data from google analytics and accordingly the data in my website will change. I want it to be automated and dynamic, like whenever the data changes in GA, i want it to be automatically changed in our website, which will be shown to our clients to show the performance of our websites.

I am guessing this can be achieved by some api calling from php, xml returned values and showing those data on our website along with images.

i would appreciate if anyone could give me more info on how to start working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics has an official [API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html). They don't seem to have ready-made PHP examples, but the XML sources should be easy to query. Not sure how "live" GA's data is, though - it could be that it is not possible to do stuff live tracking of visitors.

Comment: GA has a 24 hour delay on data

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have seen other classes in php like GAPI. I wanted to know if there is anything better than that?

Also if I am using the official API, will i be able to get images or only values of the data?

Comment: 24 hour dealy is as good as LIVE. Not much problem with that though.

Comment: 24 hour delay is as good as LIVE? LMAO.  I do a lot of tracking code implementation and QA and let me tell you, 24 hour delay on finding out whether something works or trying to QA really f'in sucks.

Comment: So according to your situation it wont work well..but for my situation, YES it is as good as LIVE.